# Precautions when re-establishing contact between AD sites

Tags: active-directory

We have an AD with two sites, two DCs in each. One of the sites is being rebuilt, and all machines except the domain controllers were shut down. Five days ago, due to a firewall upgrade misfortune, we lost the VPN between the sites. We are now about to reestablish the tunnel, and I'm getting a bit worried about if there could be issues with conflict resolution when the domain controllers can communicate again. There have been a set of changes on the domain controllers in the "live" datacenter, including joining member servers. I haven't been able to find any advice about such situations, and MSDN/TechNet only details the conflict resolution algorithm.

Is there anything I should ensure before opening the tunnel again? Anything specific to look out for? I didn't anticipate losing contact, and all the FSMO roles resided on one of the domain controllers in the "lost site", does that make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict process is described below.  I'm not sure what you mean by issue, but if there is a conflict, the changes on one side will be lost in favor of the other side.

Tracking Updates
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961798.aspx

"Active Directory replication does not use timestamps as the primary mechanism to determine what updates "win" (are preserved) in a conflict resolution. Instead, Active Directory uses volatility (number of changes) as the first element of the per-attribute "stamps" that are compared during conflict resolution. The second element is a timestamp. So if an attribute is updated once on domain controller A and once on domain controller B, the last writer's update wins. But if the attribute is updated twice on domain controller A and once on domain controller B, the update of domain controller A wins even if the clock of domain controller B is set forward to December 31, 9999. With Active Directory, clock skew can never prevent a value from being overwritten."